# Database Design: linking 2 tables with foreign keys in both

Tags: mysql

I am designing a small database and am having trouble with 2 tables. I have a team and registeredAccount table. A registered account can have 0 or 1 teams. A team has a team manager, which is a registered account.

I am struggling to link the registeredAccountId into the team table. An sql error occurs saying that it cannot add the foreign key in the team table.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to design this better, that would be great.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE team(

    teamId       INT PRIMARY KEY,
    teamName         VARCHAR(20),
    teamManagerId   INT,
    CONSTRAINT team_fk_registeredAccount
        FOREIGN KEY (teamManagerId)
        REFERENCES registeredAccount(registeredAccountId)
);

CREATE TABLE registeredAccount(

    registeredAccountId  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    displayName      VARCHAR(20),
    subscribed       BOOLEAN,
    teamId       INT,
    CONSTRAINT registeredAccount_fk_team
    FOREIGN KEY (teamId)
        REFERENCES team(teamId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set foreign key on registered account since it can be null and is independent of team
A team has a team manager. that is where you set the relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE team(

    teamId       INT PRIMARY KEY,
    teamName         VARCHAR(20),
    teamManagerId   INT,
    CONSTRAINT team_fk_registeredAccount
        FOREIGN KEY (teamManagerId)
        REFERENCES registeredAccount(registeredAccountId)
);

CREATE TABLE registeredAccount(

    registeredAccountId  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    displayName      VARCHAR(20),
    subscribed       BOOLEAN,
    teamId       INT,
    CONSTRAINT registeredAccount_fk_team
        FOREIGN KEY (teamId)
        REFERENCES team(teamId)
);
```

Comment: You are missing the `teamId` attribute on `registeredAccount`, otherwise there is no link between a team **member** and the team they are on. If you want to be completely normalized, create a 3rd relation of `registeredAccountId (pk, fk), teamID (fk)`.